# Search for a variable from vector of objects

Tags: c++, vector, stl-algorithm

```
struct ABC
{
int a;
string b;
};
```

I have a vector of objects to the above struct. And want to search the vector based on variable "b"?

I have logic as below.

```
vector<ABC> vec = ...;//vec has my objects
for(vector<ABC>::iterator it = vec.begin();
        it != vec.end();
        ++it)
    {
        if(search_str == (it->b))//search string is my string which i need to search
        {
        }
    }
```

I have extensively tested the above code and it works. I want to know if there is a better way to achieve this. Maybe using find().

Comment: This could be done in just one line of code in modern C++: `std::find_if(vec.begin(), vec.end(), [&](const auto &e) { return e.b == search_str});`

Comment: What output do you want? The first match, if there is one? A new container of all the matching items? SOmething else?

Comment: I would like to have iterator to the first match. So that I can use the iterator to extract the values.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik I am getting auto not allowed in visual studios 2012

Comment: @arjunjawalkar Do you have `C++11`.?

Comment: @GauravSehgal generic lambdas are C++14. It can simply be replaced with `const ABC&` here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simple, readable, lifted from [Sam's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47941186/search-for-a-variable-from-vector-of-objects#comment82851675_47941186):

```
auto found = std::find_if(vec.begin(), vec.end(), [&](auto const &e) {
    return e.b == search_str;
});
```

And now `found` is an iterator to the first matching element, or `vec.end()` if none was found.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use range based for loops in some cases, give you much clearer code.

```
for (auto const &p : vec)
{
    if (p == search_str)
    {
        //--- Handle the find ---//

        //if you want to stop...
        break; 
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

One of the better method to compare two strings is using `compare` method in C++.

Suppose you want to compare two strings S1 and S2. 
 You can use `equality operator( == )` as you have already used.
But using `std::string::compare()` function has it's own benefit.
We can not only compare two strings but can also check if one is less or greater.
`std::string::compare()` function return an `int`:

- zero if `S1` is equal to `S2`.
- less than zero if `S1` is less than `S2`.
- greater than zero if `S1` is greater than `S2`.

So your code can be formatted as:

```
vector<ABC> vec = ...;//vec has my objects
for(vector<ABC>::iterator it = vec.begin(); it != vec.end(); ++it){
    if(!search_str.compare(it->b))
    {
      //match found
    }
}
```

Comment: How is the additional information returned by `compare` "better" if you don't use it at all?

Comment: In that case it is almost same. I have pointed out another way to search for the string as asked. There's no harm in telling the other functionalities. And better in sense that if in future, you need to check for greater or less, then your code will be more modular.